Textformfield unfocus when onTapOutside but not onScroll
In a TextFormField I'm trying to unfocus with onTapOutside instead of using a GestureDetector, to unfocus when I tap outside the TextFormField.
onTapOutside: (pointer) {
  if (FocusScope.of(context).focusedChild != null) {
    FocusScope.of(context).focusedChild!.unfocus();
  }
},

The problem is that since we start scrolling in the page it also unfocus the field selected.
Is there a way currently to patch this problem from onTapOutside ?
Is it possible to use onTapOutside without losing the focus when scrolling ?
I've also tried the TextFieldTapRegion and it doesn't works.
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextFieldTapRegion(
          onTapOutside: (_) =>
              FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
          child: TextFormField(),
        ),
        ...List.generate(100, (_) => Text('Test')),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);


tried any of TextFieldTapRegion / TapRegion / TapRegionSurface etc?

It doesn't change anything of the onTapOutside

i used TextFieldTapRegion and it seems to work fine - when scrolling no focus is lost

@pskink I've updated the question with the use of TextFieldTapRegion which doesn't work for me in my case. Ever since I'm scrolling in my page I loose the focus of my TextFormField.

TextFieldTapRegion must be a parent of Column

I tried to put it everywhere and no it doesn't work. When it is the parent of the column it works only when we scroll on the text, when It is the parent of the SingleChildScrollView then it doesn't unfocus on scroll but also on tap so ...

return Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0), child: Container( color: Colors.grey, child: TextFieldTapRegion( onTapOutside: (e) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(), child: SingleChildScrollView( child: Column( children: [ for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12), child: i.isEven? const TextField( decoration: InputDecoration( border: OutlineInputBorder(), ), ) : Text('foo bar', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge), ), ], ), ), ), ), );

On your example if we tap on the "foo bar" or in the grey area the focus is still on the textfield.

so you need one GestureDetector: return Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0), child: Container( color: Colors.grey, child: TextFieldTapRegion( child: GestureDetector( onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(), child: SingleChildScrollView( child: Column( children: [ for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12), child: i.isEven? const TextField( decoration: InputDecoration( border: OutlineInputBorder(), ), ) : Text('foo bar', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge), ), ], ), ), ), ), ), );

Yes I already have GestureDetector, but the problem is that it doesn't detect when we're clicking on a button, that's why I was trying to migrate to onTapOutside but it just seems the feature isn't enough ready for that.

I don't get you: buttons work too...

Nah, when clicking a button while in the textfield it hides the keyboard to do the action like for example display a modal but when you leave the modal the focus comes back on the textfield
